# Swift: How can I set an action to occur at the completion of a CAKeyFrameAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, swift

I'm using a CAKeyFrameAnimation in a similar manner to how it's used on [this](http://mathewsanders.com/animations-in-swift-part-two/) page. I'm trying to have an action occur at the end of the animation, but I'm not sure how I can go about doing that. I looked through the CAKeyFrameAnimation docs and didn't see anything about a completionHandler or anything, and the only thing I can think to do is to set a timer for the animation length and handle everything after that. I figure there must be some better way to get notified that the animation has completed, but I haven't been able to find a better solution.

Answer (score 12):

**Swift**

Use `CATransaction.setCompletionBlock` as below.

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setCompletionBlock({
    view.isHidden = true
})

let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
animation.path = path

view.layer.add(animation, forKey: "moveIn")

CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 7):

You didn't look up the inheritance chain. `CAAnimation` has a delegate property, and a delegate method, `animationDidStop:finished:`, that you can use to detect the end of an animation.

Comment: Aww man I always forget to look up the chain in the docs :/ Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user1493950, yeah, it's easy to forget that.